# Comparing groups for hypothesis testing

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, group-differences

I have the following analysis to do: what is the relationship of age to blood pressure on overall data. Then, examine the relationship in each subgroup. I have blood pressure readings, continues quantity, and age a continues quantity. I have fitted a linear regression on overall data and found that increase in age has a linear relationship with slop of +2.2(meaning every year increase expect an increase of 2.2 in blood pressure). Now I am doing the subgroup analysis. The groups are split based on the outcome which is the blood pressure. Low, normal and high blood pressure. How do I go about analysing the subgroups to compare the relationship of age and the blood pressure and its p value for significance of difference. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please state your hypotheses. Also indicate whether you have readings measuring systolic  blood pressure ?

Comment: thanks for the comment. the hypothesis as stated, as you age would your blood pressure increase. second hypothesis: there would be a different rate of increase depending on which blood pressure group someones at. it is systolic blood pressure.

Comment: Age could be an explanatory factor,  but checki ng for effect of B.P.  on rate of increase (with age ) seems unjustified.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is not about the hypothesis justification. It is about the way i do the comparison. Lets assume it is justfiable how would i do it? Thanks in advance